# Change parameters according to phone orientation

Tags: android

I would like to set up these parameters

```
IF (the phone is in vertical orientation)
     imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(400, 400));

ELSE ()
     imageView.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(600, 600));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `getRotation()` method to check for device's rotation, and set parameters of the image when the activity restarts on the orientation change!

See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation%28%29) link for the details of the function, and use it in the `if` condition.